# Fragment cannot be converted

Tags: android, fragment

i want to create an instance of my fragment in parent activity but it show this error :

Error:(16, 81) error: incompatible types: Fragment cannot be converted to TextFragment

my code:

```
TextFragment frag =(TextFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.textFragment);
```

TextFragment code:

```
public class TextFragment extends Fragment{

private long workoutId;

public TextFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_text, container, false);
}


public void setWorkoutId(long workoutId) {
    this.workoutId = workoutId;
}

}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], including the source code for `TextFragment`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solve it.
in my TextFragment i import `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` and in my MainActivity
`import android.app.Fragment` If both must be the same.

Answer (score 1):

check if you are using wrong import

for `getFragmentManager()` the import is `android.app.Fragment`

if you are using this import `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`

then change the `getFragmentManager()` to `getSupportFragmentManager()`

**Edit**

```
TextFragment tf = new TextFragment();
getFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.textFragment,tf)
                    .commit();
```

Comment: import that but still cannot cast

Comment: is there another way to use fragment?

Comment: i change it but still show error.is that for my sdk ?

Answer (score 0):

You should be using [getSupportFragmentManager()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html#getSupportFragmentManager()), not `getFragmentManager()`.

Answer (score -1):

Check your layout file where you have written the xml tag of fragment, you have to assign TextFragment to its class attribute eg.